# Customization of GitLab notification emails

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am having a hard time finding a definitive answer on the internet. Is there a way to customize GitLab notification emails? For example, when a pipeline has passed, I want to give more precise information than the ones provided by the default sent email.

If it's not yet implemented, from where comes the email parameters (e.g., branch, commit)? I don't understand how they work.

Thanks!